# Zabbix Active check log[] logrt[]

Tags: linux, monitoring, zabbix

I'm trying to create right regexp for log file I would like to monitor, but I have tried many things and they don't work.
What I would like to monitor...
My log file looks like this:

```
17-06-14  Name                                                  Succ    Fail  Reject
11:36:33  BalanceCheck                                             2       6       10 
          Connections                                              3       0       0 
          Transfers                                                0       0       0
17-06-14  Name                                                  Succ    Fail  Reject
11:37:33  BalanceCheck                                             2       6       1 
          Connections                                              3       0       0 
          Transfers                                                50      2       10
```

The value I'm trying to have in output is for example "2". Which should be found under Succ and BalanceCheck.
I was trying to use:

```
log[/tmp/logfile,,"BalanceCheck *([0-9]+)",,,,\1]
```

But it shows in Zabbix that it is not supported, because of too many outputs.
Also I can't create a regex for Fail value to work properly....

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using:

```
log[/tmp/logfile,,"BalanceCheck *([0-9]+)",,,,\1]
```

Zabbix `log[]` key syntax is:

```
log[file,<regexp>,<encoding>,<maxlines>,<mode>,<output>,<maxdelay>]
```

Notice how the second parameter should be regexp, but you have it put in the third parameter. Try removing the first or second comma in your key.

Comment: Sorry, one " , " too much. But in zabbix I have checked and I got syntax made corectly.
`log[/tmp/logfile,"BalanceCheck *([0-9]+)",,,,\1]`

Comment: In that case please provide exact steps you performed and exact error message (including where you see it). Also, which Zabbix version is it?

Comment: I'm using zabbix 3.0.1 (I'm waiting for update).
The log from zabbix agent with set debuglevel=4 log under ->
 [ZabbixLog](https://pastebin.com/PSQ5ANSK)

Comment: Hmm, that's completely different from "too many outputs" you indicated at first. The log you provided on pastebin shows no errors. It is also still unclear where and when exactly you see the error in the frontend, please be more specific. It is quite likely that you are seeing the error from before you fixed the item key - it usually takes around 10 minutes for the new key to be used, but could be longer.

Comment: What do you think about this regexp? Does it look fine for you? Or should I write it in another way? Also, how would you write regexp to check the value of Fail?
`log[ ]` syntax is:  
`log[file,<regexp>,<encoding>,<maxlines>,<mode>,<output>]`
and `logrt[ ]` is  
`logrt[file_regexp,<regexp>,<encoding>,<maxlines>,<mode>,<output>]`

Comment: We're fishing a bit and including several questions here - that will only make things more confusing. Let's concentrate on getting one thing per question fixed.